# post two buddies with angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a post method in my backend which has 2 buddies to post :

```
@PostMapping("/final")

public Template editTemplate (@Valid @RequestBody Template temp , @Valid @RequestBody 
 ComponentLinechart lchart) {
    return service.editTemplate(temp, lchart);
}
```

I want to call this function in the frontend (angular 7) but it doesn't accept two buddies, I call it like that :

```
editTemplate(Temp : Template ,Data: ComponentLinechart): Observable<Template, ComponentLinechart> {
  return this.http.post<Template, ComponentLinechart>(this.baseUrl + '/config/final' , Temp, Data )
}
```

But it gives me a syntax errors ! How could I call it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `httpClient` in Angular accepts second argument in the form of request payload, and third argument as request options.

Try this instead:

```js
editTemplate(Temp : Template, Data: ComponentLinechart): Observable<Template> {
  return this.http.post<Template>(this.baseUrl + '/config/final', {Temp, Data});
}
```

This way your request body becomes JSON like this one:

```
{
  "Temp": ...,
  "Data": ...
}
```

Make sure to correctly accept in on your backend. I'm not sure Spring Boot can parse two arguments both of which come from `@RequestBody`. There can be only one request body in an HTTP request after all.

Comment: Thank you it works ! but I have a problem in the backend because of two requestBody I had ! Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: @foufaoueslati I believe it'll work just fine if you create another class that has both `Temp` and `Data` properties, and accept it instead as such: `(@Valid @RequestBody TempAndData body)`